# expected value rule of Uniform random variable

Tags: expected-value

Let  be a uniform random variable on the range $\{−1,0,1,2\}$. Let $=^4$. Use the expected value rule to calculate $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Why isn’t the answer $1/4 \cdot(-1)^4 +1/4\cdot (0)^4+ 1/4 \cdot(1)^4 + 1/4 \cdot(2)^4$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarize yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: Why do you think that that is not the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

The rv X is the following

$$X =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4},  & \text{if $x=-1$} \\
\frac{1}{4},  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
\frac{1}{4},  & \text{if $x=1$} \\
\frac{1}{4},  & \text{if $x=2$} 
\end{cases}$$

If you transform $Y=X^4$ when $X=\pm1$ you get that $Y=1$ in both cases, so you have

$$Y =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4},  & \text{if $y=0$} \\
\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $y=1$} \\
\frac{1}{4},  & \text{if $y=16$} 
\end{cases}$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{2}+4=\frac{9}{2}$$

Next time, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your formulas; it is easy and your message is more readeable

In any case, your answer is correct...

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=(-1)^4\times\frac{1}{4}+(0)^4\times\frac{1}{4}+(1)^4\times\frac{1}{4}+(2)^4\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{9}{2}$$